# Dropbox automated Login via PHP

Tags: php, authentication, dropbox

I have to find a solution for an automated login into Dropbox.
I'm trying to load the html code with

```
<?php $html = file_get_contents('https://www.dropbox.com/login'); ?>
```

Now I use str_replace() to set the value for the E-Mail and password. Also I cange the formular action from "/login" to "https://www.dropbox.com/login". Now I load my page and see the Dropbox-login filled with the right data.
If I click on "Login" and it say Error "403".
I know, Dropbox login requires some kind of key that is written in a hidden input field and somehow file_get_contents() doesn't deliver a valid key.
Can you help me?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that, use the API instead:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers

Comment: Yes, and I'd be interested to know what the original poster is trying to do that the API doesn't cover (if anything).

Comment: Oh, I didn't know there is an API. Thank you

Comment: I guess there is no way to run this API on a IIS7  32-bit PHP environment?